# Compiling issue

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make this compile?

and make it so it uses the fct with an integer default?

using g++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int     fct(int a = 0)
{
        printf("a: %d\n", a);
        return (0);
}

void    fct()
{
}



int     main(void)
{

        fct();
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look up what the word "ambiguous" means.

Comment: `int     fct(int a = 0)` should return a value

Comment: use `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`

Comment: Why not just remove the second function? There would then be no case where you want it called, right?

Comment: @triclosan Why?  I've yet to see an implementation of `<cstdio>` which was conform to the standard.  Whereas with `<stdio.h>`, you know what you're getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because once you added default value to `fct(int)` compiler can't guess which one you want to call:

- `fct(int)` with default value of arg
- `fct()`

What you can do is remove default value, and call `fct(0)` or remove the one without arguments completely.

Answer (score 1):

C++ wont let you compile Ambiguous code. If ambiguity is the in the code you have to try to resolve it.

Function cannot be overloaded which differs only in return type.

Check out this link for examples. http://xania.org/200711/ambiguous-overloading

the following will only work:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int     fct(int a)
    {
            printf("a: %d\n", a);
            return (0);
    }

    void    fct()
    {
        printf("a: 0\n", a);
    }



    int     main(void)
    {

            fct();
            return (0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload functions by return type alone. Let me list down the functions that are generated for your case
    `int     fct(int a = 0)`
will generate two functions (one with argument, one without) : 
    `int     fct(int a)` and `int     fct()`
In addition to above functions you have introduced another method
    `void    fct()`
So you have two methods, differed by return type
    `void    fct()` and `int     fct()`
In C++, you **CANNOT** have overloaded functions with the variation in return type alone